# How to get response from file_get_contents using php?

Tags: php, json, xml

**i try to show status of this page but show only blank page this my code please retify**
`

```
$ref_no = "123";
$postdata = http_build_query(array(
    'apiToken' => '123',
    'reqid' => ''.$ref_no.''
));
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.smslinkwallet.com/apiservice.asmx/GetRechargeStatus', false, $context);             
$decoded_json = json_decode($result, false); 
echo $decoded_json->status;
```

**this one example response page**

```
SUPPORT:HTTP GET OR HTTP POST
    RESPONSE:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Result xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <reqid>unique id sent by the client</reqid>
    <status>SUCCESS/FAILED/PENDING/FREQUENT</status>
    <remark>recharge summary</remark>
    <balance>balance after recharge</balance>
    <mn>string</mn>
    <field1>operator transaction id</field1>
    <ec>error code</ec>
    </Result>
```

`

**i try to show status of this page please help me**

Comment: Have you tried `context_create_stream` and `fopen`????

Comment: If you expect XML, why do you process it as JSON?